# Elasticsearch QueryBuilder not all fields always there

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a QueryBuilder but I have problems with fields not always being needed.

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(termQuery("country", countryName))
                    .must(termQuery("Region", regionName))
                    .must(termQuery("City", city))
                    .must(rangeQuery("persons").from(persons))
                    .get();
```

In the example above city might not always be needed, but if I leave it empty it searches for an empty city. This is just for city, but I expect 10+ fields later on.
Can I somehow conditionally add things to the builder or is there another smart way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your `query` and then pass it to the search request. During building you can conditionally add your statements to the query. It will look like this

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(termQuery("country", countryName))
        .must(termQuery("Region", regionName))
        .must(rangeQuery("persons").from(persons));

if(city != null && city.trim().equals("")) {
    queryBuilder.must(termQuery("City", city));
}

.setQuery(queryBuilder); //add query to your search request
```

Comment: thanks! I thought I had tried this, but it was in a debugging storm so I might have had it just wrong or so...